# How to remove .php from a certain file (with Apache .htaccess)?

Tags: .htaccess, seo

I want to remove the php extension for a certain file (only this!). BUT: It uses get parameters and they should remain!

I tried it with my `.htaccess` and something like: `RewriteEngine on` followed by either

`RewriteRule ^file(.*)$ file.php$1`

or

`RewriteRule ^file(.+)$ file.php$1`

But it doesn't work. (First gives error 500, second gives 404)

Example what I want to call in the browser:

`file?param=asd&foo=bar`

It should call as:

`file.php?param=asd&foo=bar`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. Maybe anyone wants to know:

`RewriteRule ^file$ file.php [QSA]`